# What is this large seating area on the Enterprise blueprints?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, uss-enterprise

On the [Star Trek Blueprints - General Plans (1973)](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/star-trek-blueprints.php) on deck 21 aft of the bowling alley there is a section that says

> **Seating Accommodation (83)**

It is not labeled as such, but would I be wrong assuming it's a theater?

[image: Blueprint titled "Deck 21 Food preparation center/bowling alley" showing a pool at the forward end of the deck, then the laundry, reclamation and food areas, followed by the bowling alley with the noted "seating accommodation" at the aft end.]

Comment: The plans are NCC-1700 Booklet of General Plans U.S.S. Constitution Class printed in 1973.

Comment: Today I learned that the *Enterprise* has a bowling alley that takes up half a deck.

Comment: Which deck are the personal isolation rooms?

Comment: I believe that most of the crew is multicultural and those that share quarters need a place to worship or meditate in private and not disturb fellow crew mates.

Comment: There are two questions here, one about the isolation rooms and one about the large seating area. Since the two answers you've had so far are focused on the latter, I've edited out the question about the iso rooms. You should ask it as a new and separate question.

Answer (score 12):

With regard to the seating, it would appear that it faces directly onto the *Enterprise*'s [bowling alley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bowling_alley) which may or may not actually exist canonically, given that its sole mention (In *TOS*: "The Naked Time") was by a man who was temporarily insane.

You can see a depiction of the front couple of rows of seating in an easter egg from the Paramount-licensed video game [*Star Trek: Secret of Vulcan Fury*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Secret_of_Vulcan_Fury)

[image: View from a seating area towards a six-lane ten-pin bowling alley with red hoods over the pins and a large silver sign reading "NCC 1701" against a green background]

Comment: The bowling alley was mentioned in the episode, *The Naked Now*. That would make it canon. Do you have a canon source which says there was no bowling alley?

Comment: @RichS - The sole mention was by a man who was temporarily insane.

Comment: @RichS - it was "The Naked TIME" in TOS, not the TNG episode "The Naked NOW"

Comment: @RichS and he also called himself captain, that didn't make it true.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the seating shown on the right-hand side of that drawing is indeed a sort of "viewing gallery" for the ship's bowling alley. BTW, there *was* a bowling alley mentioned in an episode of TOS. In "The Naked Time," after he gets infected with that virus that strips its victims of their personal inhibitions, Ensign (or is he a Lieutenant?) O'Reilly takes control of Main Engineering and serenades the whole crew with an off-key rendition of the song "I'll Take You Home Again, Kathleen." In between verses of the song, O'Reilly at one point announces that there is to be a dance held in the ship's bowling alley. This, I think, is where Franz Joseph got the idea to include the bowling alley in his blueprints. So I think one *can* consider the existence of a bowling alley on Kirk's Enterprise as canon, since it was mentioned in an episode of the series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The existence of the bowling alley was taken as given in the question.  The question was about the personal isolation rooms and the seating accommodation, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well, the seating accommodation shown on the drawing (that they were asking about) was a viewing gallery for the bowling alley, given that it was placed right behind the bowling lanes and up against the interior bulkhead of the ship's fantail/cove. Between the above screencap from that Star Trek video game, and the drawing from Franz Joseph's blueprints, it's fairly obvious what those seats were for. In real-life Terrestrial bowling alleys, they have similar rows of chairs set up for folks who just want to watch bowling games, or are awaiting their turn to play.